# Why are parenthesis needed in F# using method chaining query expression where clause?

Tags: linq, f#

Attempting to write more queries in F# through LinqPad I ran into an interesting thing with the where clause.

```
let dc = new TypedDataContext()

let q = query {
    for o in dc.OrderItem do 
    where (o.Description.Contains("spam"))
    select o
}

q |> Dump
```

If I remove the parenthesis around `o.Description.Contains("spam")` I get the often seen error message below.

> Successive arguments should be separated by spaces or tupled, and arguments involving function or method applications should be parenthesized (using external F# compiler)

When I see this error I normally realize that I'm not giving enough information in order for the compiler to understand that I'm attempting to chain off of the result of a prior method call or property get accessor invocation but in this case it is unclear to me. Additionally I'd be curious if there is a more idiomatic way of satisfying the conditions of the compiler without having to reach around the expression to add both open and closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 7):

You'd see the same result if you did something like this:

```
let f x = 1

f o.Description.Contains("spam")
```

As the message implies, if you're using the result of a method call (`Contains` in this case) as an argument to a function, then the method call needs to be parenthesized.  Even though `where` is a query operator rather than a true function, the same result applies.